# Is there a way to use FastMember ObjectReader over an expando/dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject, fastmember

Is there a way to use FastMember `ObjectReader.Create` over a list of `ExpandoObject`.

Here is a simple test case that I made to test:

```
using FastMember;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestReaderAsync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<ExpandoObject> expandos = new List<ExpandoObject>();
            var first = GetExpando();
            var second = GetExpando();
            expandos.Add(first);
            expandos.Add(second);
            var keys = (first as IDictionary<string, object>).Keys;
            using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(expandos, keys.ToArray()))
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        private static ExpandoObject GetExpando()
        {
            ExpandoObject exp = new ExpandoObject();
            exp.TryAdd("ID", "A");
            exp.TryAdd("ID_2", "B");
            exp.TryAdd("DATE", DateTime.Now);
            exp.TryAdd("MONTH", 5);
            return exp;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the problem is coming from the `GetMembers` function in `TypeAccessor`. Since `ExpandoObject` is inheriting from `IDictionary<string, object>`, the type has no properties and FastMember is not able to serialize each key of the dictionary. Is there a workaround to achieve it?

Basically, I perform SQL queries that got translated into expandos. I want to use `ObjectReader` to bulk back the result into a database.